# Borrowing error occurs when there is an assignment in an if statement

Tags: rust

The following Rust code occurs a compile error.

```rust
struct Sandbox {
    value: String,
}

impl Sandbox {
    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        let mut value = &self.value;

        while true {
            // Call any function of value
            value.as_str();

            // The error occurs here
            self.change();

            if true {
                value = self.get_value();
            }
        }
    }

    fn change(&mut self) {}

    fn get_value(&self) -> &String {
        &self.value
    }
}
```

The error says `cannot borrow *self as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable`. So I thought the problem was to do an immutable borrow with "self.get_value()" and then do a mutable borrow with "self.change()".

But when I removed the "if true" statement or added a "else" statement, the error disappeared. I cannot understand how the "if" statement effects borrowing or mutable. So can someone give me some details?

```rust
// Occurs an error
if true {
    value = self.get_value();
}
```

```rust
// No error
value = self.get_value();
```

### Error message

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/sandbox.rs:13:13
   |
6  |         let mut value = &self.value;
   |                         ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |             value.as_str();
   |             -------------- immutable borrow later used here
...
13 |             self.change();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

### Rust version

rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)

Comment: I can't replicate the behavior you're describing - if I comment out the `if` statement, I get the same error as before.

Comment: @JoeClay Which version of Rust are you using? I think the behavior may be different for versions.

Comment: Since you are just retrieving `self.value`. Would [this](https://gist.github.com/6801df886df2e708c488fced9f0b6dd5) be what you want?

Comment: @Yamamoto: Ah, I see where I've gone wrong - I was commenting out the entire block, including `value = self.get_value()`. With that line left in, I do in fact get the same behaviour.

Comment: @mdmundo This code is extremely simplified. Actually "get_value" returns one of some member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `if`, the statement always executes. Thus, there is no immutable borrow held while borrowing mutably: the borrow will be overwritten before being used in the next execution of the loop.

However, if it's gated behind an `if` (even `if true`, as the compiler does not evaluate the condition) it can not execute, causing the borrow of `self` to be held until we do `value.as_str()` in the next loop execution, and during that time we call `self.change()` which needs to borrow `self` mutably.